# Juju charm: action failed: (ImportError: No module named 'charms.reactive')

Tags: cloud, juju, charm

As a newbie to `juju` framework, I'm invistigating simple `machine` deployment with the aim of executing simple `action` on it.

So, I've created a `charm` bundle, built it and deployed it successfully using `juju`.  The bundle contains an `action` called "touch" that takes a string (i.e.: filename) as an input and create a file with that name on the machine.

After the machine becomes "active" and when I list actions in the deployed machine using:

```
juju actions charmLayer
```

I get my `action` listed alongside its description.

Now, when executing the actions "touch" using:

```
juju run-action charmLayer/0 touch filename="/home/ubuntu/manual.txt"
```

I get the following message:

> Action queued with id: d6b39965-9a2c-41c6-8db7-b4060e587033

Then, when I check the action-status:

```
juju show-action-status d6b39965-9a2c-41c6-8db7-b4060e587033
```

I get the following:

> actions:
>
> action: touch
>
> completed at: "2019-05-03 11:56:51"
>
> id: d6b39965-9a2c-41c6-8db7-b4060e587033
>
> status: failed
>
> unit:
>
> charmLayer/0

Then when I check the action-output:

```
juju show-action-output d6b39965-9a2c-41c6-8db7-b4060e587033
```

I get the following:

> message: exit status 1
>
> status: failed
>
> timing:
>
> completed: 2019-05-03 11:56:51 +0000 UTC
>
> enqueued: 2019-05-03 11:56:48 +0000 UTC
>
> started: 2019-05-03 11:56:51 +0000 UTC

when checking logs using :

```
juju debug-log
```

I see the following output:

> unit-charmLayer-0: 13:23:14 DEBUG unit.charmLayer/0.touch Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> unit-charmLayer-0: 13:23:14 DEBUG unit.charmLayer/0.touch   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-charmLayer-0/charm/actions/touch", line 6, in
>
> unit-charmLayer-0: 13:23:14 DEBUG unit.charmLayer/0.touch from charms.reactive import main, set_flag
>
> unit-charmLayer-0: 13:23:14 DEBUG unit.charmLayer/0.touch ImportError: No module named 'charms.reactive'

**My question why am I getting this `ImportError` for the `charms.reactive` ?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?  We might be able to help if we can see how you've composed your charm.  (this should be a comment, not an answer.  I don't have the rep).

In answer, are you importing charms.reactive?  If you're writing a reactive charm it should have been included for you already if you did `charm init`.  Otherwise you might need to add `import charms.reactive` at the top of your Python script.